# how to understand this define macro?

Tags: android, c

I am learning Dalvik VM code but stopped by some strange C define macros in file *InterpC-portable.cpp*. They're hard to understand for me. The code is:

```
# define H(_op)             &&op_##_op
```

and in file *libdex/DexOpcodes.h*, it is used like this:

```
#define DEFINE_GOTO_TABLE(_name) \
  static const void* _name[kNumPackedOpcodes] = {                      \
  /* BEGIN(libdex-goto-table); GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY BY opcode-gen */ \
  H(OP_NOP),                                                            \
  H(OP_MOVE),                                                           \
  H(OP_MOVE_FROM16),                                                    \
  ...
```

OP_NOP, OP_MOVE, OP_MOVE_FROM16 are some *enum* variable. But what's the meaning of *&&* operation in H(_op) macro? It doesn't make sense to get a pointer of pointer which doesn't store at memory. Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: not exactly what you asked, but if you use `GCC` you can compile using `-E` flag to stop the compilation after pre-processing and see how the `#define` was evaluated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&&` is the **label value operator**. It returns he addres of a label defined in the current scope, used as operand. It is a `gcc` extension.

Comment: What I'm not getting are the underscores. Shouldn't the macro be `&&_op##_op` instead? How would evaluate `H(foo)`?